# Do the parity matrices of $\text{CSS}(C_1, C_2)$ and $\text{CSS}_{u,v}(C_1, C_2)$ need to be same and the Number of Distinct Equivalent Descriptions?

Tags: error-correction, nielsen-and-chuang

This question relates to Exercise 10.27 of Nielsen & Chuang, which says:

> Show that the codes defined by
> $$| x + C_2 \rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{C_2}} \sum\limits_{y \in C_2} (-1)^{u \cdot y} | x+y+v \rangle$$
> and parameterized by $u$ and $v$ are equivalent to $\text{CSS}(C_1, C_2)$ in the sense that they have the same error-correcting properties.

[A similar question has been posted here.](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/8742/nielsen-chuang-exercise-question-on-css-code) It seems that the solution suggests that the parity check matrix of the parameterized version of the CSS codes and non-parameterized version are the same. As far as I understand CSS codes with different parity matrices could "have the same error-correcting properties". So do the parity matrix of $\text{CSS}_{u,v}(C_1, C_2)$ and $\text{CSS}(C_1, C_2)$ have to be the same?

In light of this question, how many distinct equivalent descriptions of $\text{CSS}(C_1, C_2)$ are there?

Answer (score 1):

> It seems that the solution suggests that the parity check matrix of
> the parameterized version of the CSS codes and non-parameterized
> version are the same.

In essence this is correct but there is a very minor technicality based on what you take the definition of a CSS code to be. In Nielsen and Chuang, a CSS code is the subspace spanned by states $$|x + C_2 \rangle = \sum\limits_{y \in C_2} | x+y\rangle$$ for some choice of length $n$ binary linear codes $C_1,C_2$ such that $C_2 \subseteq C_1$. This definition is equivalent to a CSS code being the subspace stabilized by the $n$-qubit Pauli operators that are tensor products of only $X$ or only $Z$ operators which can be found from the parity check matrices of $C_1$ and $C_2^{\perp}$. These Pauli operators are also called parity checks for the CSS code because they all act as the identity matrix on the code. With these definitions, $\text{CSS}_{u,v}(C_1, C_2)$ is generally not a CSS code so there are no parity check Pauli operators to speak of.

However, the parity checks of $\text{CSS}(C_1, C_2)$ can be used to describe all possible $\text{CSS}_{u,v}(C_1, C_2)$ which the solution to the question you linked describes. Within the scope of Nielsen and Chuang, the idea is illustrated by Proposition 10.5. If you have a CSS code $\text{CSS}(C_1, C_2)$ where $k = \dim(C_1)-\dim(C_2)$ then from the parity check matrices of $C_1$ and $C_2^{\perp}$ you can construct independent parity check operators $g_1,\ldots,g_{n-k}$. For each length $n-k$ binary vector $x = (x_1,\ldots,x_{n-k})$ we may define $Q_x \subseteq (\mathbb{C}^2)^{n}$ as the subspace where $g_i|\phi\rangle = (-1)^{x_i}|\phi\rangle$ for each $1 \leq i \leq n-k$ and all $|\phi\rangle \in Q_x$. In other words, $Q_x$ is an eigenspace of each $g_i$ with eigenvalue $(-1)^{x_i}$. Each $Q_x$ is distinct and in fact pair-wise orthogonal. The idea is that each of these $Q_x$ can be used as a quantum code. In particular, if $x = (0,0,\ldots,0)$ then $Q_x = \text{CSS}(C_1, C_2)$ and for any other choice of $x$, you get some parametrized $\text{CSS}_{u,v}(C_1, C_2)$. The operators $g_1,\ldots,g_{n-k}$ can also be used as parity checks for $Q_x$; when you measure the observables $g_1,\ldots,g_{n-k}$ a result of $(-1)^{x_1},\ldots,(-1)^{x_n}$ will tell you that the state is in $Q_x$. Each of these codes have the same error correcting capabilities and in light of this, we can just classify all these $Q_x$'s as CSS codes (this was actually the original presentation in [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/9605005)). So in conclusion, $\text{CSS}(C_1, C_2)$ and $\text{CSS}_{u,v}(C_1, C_2)$ are described by the same classical parity check matrices coming from $C_1$ and $C_2$ but different quantum measurements/parity checks.

> In light of this question, how many distinct equivalent descriptions of $\text{CSS}(C_1, C_2)$ are there?

In the previous paragraph it was stated that each $\text{CSS}_{u,v}(C_1, C_2)$ is one of the $Q_x$'s. From this there are $2^{n-k}$ distinct $\text{CSS}_{u,v}(C_1, C_2)$ and furthermore we can describe when different pairs of $(u,v)$ yield the same code by an elementary computation. If $a$ is a length $n$ binary vector, define $Z_a = Z_1^{a_1} \cdots Z_n^{a_n}$ and $X_a = X_1^{a_1} \cdots X_n^{a_n}$ (i.e. $Z_a$ and $X_a$ act by $Z$ and $X$ on the qubits corresponding to nonzero components of $a$). The parity check operators of $\text{CSS}(C_1, C_2)$ are given by $Z_a$ for $a \in C_1^{\perp}$, $X_a$ for $a \in C_2$, and all products formed by these operators. Now if $a \in C_1^\perp \subseteq C_2^{\perp}$ then $$\begin{aligned}
Z_a| x + C_2 \rangle &= \sum\limits_{y \in C_2} (-1)^{u \cdot y} Z_a| x+y+v \rangle \\
&= \sum\limits_{y \in C_2} (-1)^{u \cdot y} (-1)^{a \cdot (x + y + v)}| x+y+v \rangle \\
&= \sum\limits_{y \in C_2} (-1)^{u \cdot y} (-1)^{a \cdot v}| x+y+v \rangle \\
&= (-1)^{a \cdot v}| x + C_2 \rangle
\end{aligned}$$ and if $a \in C_2$ then $$\begin{aligned}
X_a| x + C_2 \rangle &= \sum\limits_{y \in C_2} (-1)^{u \cdot y} X_a| x+y+v \rangle \\
&= \sum\limits_{y \in C_2} (-1)^{u \cdot (a+y) + u \cdot a}|x+(a+y)+v \rangle \\
&= \sum\limits_{y' \in C_2} (-1)^{u \cdot y'} (-1)^{a \cdot u}| x+y'+v \rangle \\
&= (-1)^{a \cdot u}| x + C_2 \rangle.
\end{aligned}$$ So, $\text{CSS}_{u,v}(C_1, C_2)$ is indeed an eigenspace of each of these operators and $\text{CSS}_{u_1,v_1}(C_1, C_2) = \text{CSS}_{u_2,v_2}(C_1, C_2)$ if and only if $(-1)^{u_1 \cdot a} = (-1)^{u_2 \cdot a}$ for each $a \in C_1^{\perp}$ and $(-1)^{v_1 \cdot a} = (-1)^{v_2 \cdot a}$ for each $a \in C_2$. $(-1)^{u_1 \cdot a} = (-1)^{u_2 \cdot a}$ is equivalent to $a \cdot u_1 = a \cdot u_2$ (modulo 2) which is equivalent to $a \cdot (u_1 - u_2) = 0$ meaning $u_1 - u_2 \in (C_1^{\perp})^{\perp} = C_1$. Similarly, we must have that $v_1 - v_2 \in C_2^{\perp}$. Thus for every pair $(u_1,v_2)$, there exists $|C_1| \times |C_2^{\perp}| = 2^{k_1} \times 2^{n-k_2}$ other pairs $(u_2,v_2)$ such that $\text{CSS}_{u_1,v_1}(C_1, C_2) = \text{CSS}_{u_2,v_2}(C_1, C_2)$. Hence there are $$\frac{2^n \times 2^n}{2^{\dim(C_1)} \times 2^{n-\dim(C_2)}} = 2^{n - (\dim(C_1) - \dim(C_2))} = 2^{n-k}$$ distinct $\text{CSS}_{u,v}(C_1, C_2)$.