# Which stabilizer generators of a CSS code follow from which parity check matrices?

Tags: nielsen-and-chuang, stabilizer-code

Do I have the right correspondence below between $X$-type ($Z$-type) stabilizer generators and the rows of the parity check matrices of $C_2^\perp$ ($C_1$)? I ask because it seems Nielsen and Chuang give the opposite.

---

I am making my way through Nielsen and Chuang's error-correction chapter. In the following, $x,y,k,l$ will be length-$n$ bitstrings.

The quantum codewords of a CSS code are determined by two sets of classical codewords $C_1, C_2$ with $C_2 \subset C_1$: for all of the $|C_2|/|C_1|$ cosets $x+C_2$, we define

$$|x+C_2\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{|C_2|}}\sum_{y\in C_2}|x+y\rangle $$

I am trying to understand what the stabilizers are for this code.

---

First, I consider $Z$-type stabilizers of the form $(-1)^a\prod_{i=1}^n Z^{k_i}_i$.

$$(-1)^a\prod_{i=1}^n Z^{k_i}_i|x+C_2\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{|C_2|}}\sum_{y\in C_2}(-1)^{a+k\cdot(x+y)}|x+y\rangle $$

For all $x \in C_1$, for all $y \in C_2$, we need $a+k\cdot(x+y)=0$. From the fact that the all-zero bitstring is in both $C_1$ and $C_2$, we get that $a=0$ and that $k\cdot x=0$ and $k\cdot y=0$. To summarize, the only $Z$-type stabilizers are exactly those for which $S = \prod_{i=1}^n Z_i^{k_i}\text{ where }k\in C_1^\perp$. Equivalently, since every vector in $C_1^\perp$ can be written as a linear combination of rows of the parity check matrix of $C_1$, we can identify $Z$-type stabilizer generators from the rows of the parity check matrix of $C_1$.

---

Next, consider $X$-type stabilizers of the form $\prod_{i=1}^n X_i^{l_i}$ (by inspection, we already cannot have a -1 phase).

$\prod_{i=1}^n X_i^{l_i} |x+C_2\rangle = |x+l+C_2\rangle$

We have $|x+C_2\rangle=|x+l+C_2\rangle$ if and only if $l \in C_2$.

That is, we can identify $X$-type stabilizer generators from the columns of the generating matrix of $C_2$, or, equivalently, from the rows of the parity check matrix of $C_2^\perp$.

---

It's straightforward to argue that any product of both $Z$ and $X$ terms that stabilizes the state must necessarily be a product of $Z$ and $X$-type stabilizers.

Thus, our stabilizer generators consist of $Z$-type stabilizer generators with weight given by the support of the rows of the $C_1$ parity check matrix, and $X$-type stabilizer generators with weight given by the support of the rows of the $C_2^\perp$ parity check matrix.

---

I want to confirm the above picture. The reason I ask is that on page 456 of my copy of Nielsen and Chuang, the authors identify the $X$-type stabilizers with the rows of the $C_1$ parity check matrix, and the $Z$-type stabilizer generators with the support of the rows of $C_2^\perp$ parity check matrix, which is opposite to mine. I would have chalked this up to a typo (easy to make, since this identification was made for the Steane code for which the $C_1$ and $C_2^\perp$ parity check matrices are identical), but I have seen this statement repeated elsewhere, such as in [this answer](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/a/32108/19506) which states "This definition is equivalent to a CSS code being the subspace stabilized by the $n$-qubit Pauli operators that are tensor products of only $X$ or only $Z$ operators which can be found from the parity check matrices of $C_1$ and $C_2^{\perp}$."

Do I have the right correspondence between $X$-type ($Z$-type) stabilizer generators and the rows of the parity check matrices of $C_2^\perp$ ($C_1$)? Or am have I flipped them somehow?